# Which one to choose for project work?

Tags: hardware

Hi I'm a final year college student (Engineering) and I'm trying to build a **hexapod (spider like robot)** for my final year project. The bot should be able to **Livestream** *(Video and Audio)*. So my friends were suggesting to go for a *Beaglebone Black*, but I'm thinking of using *Raspberry Pi*, so will the Raspberry Pi be able to do all the above mentioned *functions* like (or similar to) Beaglebone Black???

**Cost** is also a matter, as we have to buy other supportive peripherals too!

If you are supporting Raspberry Pi, guide me with the correct version of the Raspberry Pi capable of all this *(coz many are available in the market, and I just cannot deduce them from the specs)*

Please help me

Comment: With all due respect isn't deciding between the options available, balancing cost vs. functionality etc. Something a final year engineering student should be able to do? Also, wouldn't asking this question here,at the very least, produce a biased/subjective response? Have you asked this on the BeagleBone site? As for cost as @joan points out the chassis and servos will cost far more than either a Raspberry Pi or BeagleBone Black.

Comment: I would look around and see if you have anyone confirming (with an unambiguous explanation of exactly how) they have live low-latency video streaming working with either device.  As far as I'm aware, it's a dubious prospect on the pi and also uses a fair chunk of available CPU time.  If you are comfortable with a few seconds of latency, then you're fine, but if you want to use it to control the bot remotely, obviously that's no good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are really calling for opinions so your post is likely to be closed as off topic.

I'd have thought there wouldn't be much in hardware terms between the Beaglebone Black and the Raspberry Pi.

Where (I believe) the Pi will win hands down will be in getting help when things don't appear to be working.  The Pi community is so much larger.

The B+ is the model to go for on the Pi side.

A hexapod is a pretty challenging task and requires an awful lot of servos (3 per limb?).  That will require a lot of power.  It may have been better to choose a simpler style of robot.

This [link](http://www.mikronauts.com/robot-zoo/hexpi-hexapod-pi-robot/) may be of interest,